# How to change function iteratively as a function of its previous form?

Tags: functions, infinite-loop

I am trying to do the following :-

```
f[x_] := {x, 2}; 

 Do[f[x_] :=Append[f[x], {x, 4}],{3}] % runs into recursion limit
```

because I want to grow my function (which is a list of functions) in a loop ? What is the right way to do this ?

Comment: What are you *actually* trying to do?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Give more examples of the input and desired output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Constructing functions using codes (like the use of macros in LISPs) is completely possible in Mathematica but can be tricky, particularly if one expects the Hold and Evaluate operators to behave analogously to the quote/eval functions in LISPs. There are many ways to accomplish what you ask about; here is one:

```
Block[
  {x}, (* make sure x has no replacement in this block *)
  f[x_] = Join[{x,2}, Table[{x,4}, {3}]]];
f[1]
```

> {1, 2, {1, 4}, {1, 4}, {1, 4}}

```
?f
```

> f[x_]={x,2,{x,4},{x,4},{x,4}}

The reason for the [`Block`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Block.html) is that otherwise, the x is evaluated prior to assignment; e.g.:

```
x = 10;
(* no block *)
f[x_] = Join[{x,2}, Table[{x,4}, {3}]];
f[1]
```

> {10, 2, {10, 4}, {10, 4}, {10, 4}}

```
?f
```

> f[x_]={10,2,{10,4},{10,4},{10,4}}

Another way to do this is to use the [SetDelayed](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html) ([:=](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html)) operator for function assignment (as one usually does with functions) rather than the [Set](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html) ([=](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html)), but force the right-hand-side to be evaluated (this is basically equivalent to the above). [Evaluate](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Evaluate.html), in this context, forces the right-hand-side to be evaluated as code prior to being assigned as the replacement (aka, function body) of the pattern on the left-hand-side, `f[x_]`. This means that if `x` has a value and we don't use a `Block`, the value gets saved in the function instead of the pattern symbol `x`.

```
Block[
  {x},
  f[x_] := Evaluate@Join[{x, 2}, Table[{x, 4}, {3}]]];
f[1]
```

> {1, 2, {1, 4}, {1, 4}, {1, 4}}

```
?f
```

> f[x_]:={x,2,{x,4},{x,4},{x,4}}

There are a number of reasons it's not particularly advisable to use Append for important/time-sensitive code, but if you think you need to use it, here is an example of how that might look:

```
f[x_] := {x, 2};
?f
```

> f[x_]:={x,2}

```
(* ... somewhere else in the program ... *)
Block[
  {x},
  f[x_] := Evaluate@Append[f[x], {x, 4}]];
f[1]
```

> {1, 2, {1, 4}}

```
?f
```

> f[x_]:={x,2,{x,4}}

Answer (score 0):

This can be done pretty neatly with `Nest` in which case everything is built before assigning it to your function.

```
f[x_,n1_,n2_,n3_]:=Nest[Append[#,{x,n2}]&,{x,n1},n3]
f[x, 2, 4, 3]
{x, 2, {x, 4}, {x, 4}, {x, 4}}
```

Now you can set the constants and number of repetitions as you like each time.  If you only want one or two things to change then just fix the `n`'s to constants.

Answer (score -1):

I can do something like :-

```
    f[x_] := {x, 2}; 
Do[g[x_] = Join[f[x], {{x, 4}}]; f[x_] = g[x]; Clear[g], {3}]
```

I will accept better answers if there are. Thanks

Comment: If this is the desired behavior, then why not just define `f[x_] := {x, 2, {x, 4}, {x, 4}, {x, 4}};`?

Comment: Because here the loop runs 3 times only for example, in actual code, I want to run for larger number of times and different for different cases.